# Crystal Report multiplication error in formulas (not rounding)

Tags: sql, math, crystal-reports

Strangest thing happened just now.

I have row in a report which is a db value (Quantity - number value 51) and a formula for a Price resulting in number value 0.8. I just wanted simple multiplication 51 * 0.8 which should yield 40.80, but instead CR is giving me 40.6. I test it and try Quantity + Price (51 + 0.8). CR gives me correct 51.8 but 51 * 0.8 still 40.6.

Error is the same for all similar data (slightly lower than it should be).

Now, i resolved it by turning to SQL Expression fields, and got it working, but i wanted to share this with you.

Maybe I am missing something, or doing something in a very bad way, so any hints would be appreciated.

Regards,

UPDATE:

51 is strait from database:

```
{LineItem.Quant}
```

0.8 is calculated:

```
PriceNoVAT: {LineItem.Price} * (100 - {LineItem.TAX}) / 100
PriceAfterDiscount: {@PriceNoVAT} * (100 - {LineItem.Discount}) / 100
PriceVAT: {@PriceAfterDiscount} * (100 + {LineItem.TAX}) / 100
```

I want:

```
LineTotal: {LineItem.Quant} * {@PriceVAT}
```

This yiedls:

```
51 * 0.8 = 40.6 (Should be 40.8)
```

I put all three fields in paper design (Quant, PriceVAT and LineTotal) and I can see them in preview: 51, 0.8 and 40.6 respectively. So CR calculates 0.8 correctly (I am expecting 0.8) but not final multiplication.

At the same time if I try

```
LineTotal: {LineItem.Quant} + {@PriceVAT}
```

that yields correctly:

```
51 + 0.8 = 51.8
```

CR always calculates this incorrectly (or me doing something wrong for that matter), for all similar data.

So, there you have it, I am baffled. I am by no means CR expert, but I am also no beginner. This is nothing I would expect posting questions about, but still :)

Comment: Every numeric field in CR has some level of rounding or decimal clipping going on when it's displayed on the report canvas. It's likely that either your before or after values aren't really what you think they are. Check your numeric fields' formatting to see what kind of rounding/clipping is going on.

Comment: Is ` 51 * 0.8` is a hardcoded value or you are using some calculation that produces  `51 * 0.8`. If yes then paste the calculation in question.